# 'nodeunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I'm following "Learning To Program - Part 1: Getting Started"(
by Scott Allen) Test module .Here I'm trying to do unit testing using nodeunit. 
My AppData folder structure
[image]

I have installed nodeunit into my project using "npm install nodeunit"
[image]

Also add environment variable NODE_PATH

[image]

But when I run nodeunit in project directory in CMD it gives below error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want call this command from everywhere in command line, you should add the command folder to `PATH` environment variable too.

Run this command, replacing the correctness path.

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;<your-new-path>"
```

And restart the console.